# Where can I ask sensor related questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Can anyone guide me through a place where I can ask sensor related questions? I am building a new type of hardware which uses some traditional sensors in a new way. (ie) for Proximity sensor, I am using it in a different way. Thus I need help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can ask it on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), with the [sensor] tag.